# Error message "Not existing role" when creating activation on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'd like to install thhe AWS SSM agent to my server to be monitored by CloudWatch and found that I have to create a managed-instance activation first as this article, [Create a Managed-Instance Activation for a Hybrid Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-managed-instance-activation.html).

It always shows an error message:

> "Not existing role: arn:aws:iam::75....:role/service-role/AmazonEC2RunCommandRoleForManagedInstances".

It has the same error even I use my existing IAM role.

Anything I need to do before creating activation? Or do I have to create a special role for this?

Answer (score 3):

It's because this role didn't add "ssm.amazonaws.com" in its "Trust Relationship". After adding ssm in trust relationship, it works. refer [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/zh_cn/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-access.html?icmpid=docs_ec2_console)

Answer (score 0):

If you ran the command line example you can solve it by adding the IAM role parameter with "service-role" prepended, as following:

> --iam-role "service-role/AmazonEC2RunCommandRoleForManagedInstances"